# How to draw on top of winforms controls with transparency?

Tags: winforms, graphics

I have an app with a bunch of controls in it and I want to place a set of cross hairs on top of it. My first attack used a `PictureBox` and ran into [this problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx). The solution that fellow proposes, seems a bit... verbose for what I need.

*Is there a simple way draw on top of my form?* Note that I don't even need the drawing to be part of a control as it doesn't need to do anything but just be there.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/GraphicalOverlayComponent.aspx) eventually worked. I had to play some games though because most of the controls I wanted to draw on were not where it expected them to be.

Also, it ran into issues when controls were moved; it failed to redraw and stuff moved with the underlying control. This was fixed by forcing invalidation from the move event for anything that might move.

Answer (score 0):

Does a `PictureBox` with a transparent image have the same problem as a `Panel` with `BackColor` set to `Transparent`? I'm thinking you could have a `PictureBox` with the crosshair image in it and move *that* around, instead of drawing it yourself...

Comment: PictureBox is only transparent re it's parent. As far as other controls go, it paints over them with whatever it's parent would have panted there. There is a picture of that at the top of the link in the question.